# Installing Cursive plugin on WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, webstorm, clojurescript

I'm trying to install Cursive plugin to WebStorm 9 for **ClojureScript**. However, the plugin doesn't show up on 'Browse repository' tab in Setting->Plugin menu.

I tried to install it through downloading the plugin file from [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8090?pr=idea&showAllUpdates=true) and adding it from the disk, but WebStorm shows an error **'Error: Plugin Cursive is incompatible with current installation'**.

Is there any way to install the plugin on WebStorm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cursive needs Java plug-in. Currently Java is not supported in WebStorm. It is possible that JetBrains are working on some basic support of Java in WebStorm and other Idea derivatives. To run Cursive you have to install Idea CE side by side with WebStorm or upgrade to Idea Ultimate.

Comment: This is correct - Cursive depends on the Java support, and that is not currently available in WebStorm. There is a project at JetBrains to refactor the Java support into a normal plugin (currently it's special in several ways for historical reasons), and at that point it should be possible to install it in WebStorm (and PyCharm, RubyMine etc).

Answer (score 4):

[Doesn't look like it.](https://cursive-ide.com/userguide/)  Or, it's not explicitly supported.

> Cursive will work with IntelliJ versions 14, 14.1 and 15.

It *does* mention, earlier in that paragraph, that you should be able to use the Community Edition with it, though.

> If you don’t have a licence for the Ultimate Edition, the free Community Edition is fine.